# How to generate a custom color scale for plotly heatmap in R

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

I would like to get a custom color scale which looks like for plotly heatmap (`plot_ly(z = data, colors = customcolors, type = "heatmap")`)

```
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "blue", "lightblue1",
                          "green","yellow", "red", "darkred"))
plot(rep(1,50),col=palette(50), pch=19, cex=3, xlab = "", ylab ="", axes = F)
```

and where the blue end represents 1 and red end represents 10^6 and plotted data would have varying values on this interval.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code you use to generate a color palette works just fine. You only need to provide data that match with a `heatmap`. The following code provides this:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotly)

# your palette definition
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "blue", "lightblue1",
                              "green","yellow", "red", "darkred"))

set.seed(9876)    # for reproducibility

## a complete random set
hmdata <- matrix(data = sample(x = 1:10^6, size = 100*100), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
plot_ly(z = hmdata, colors = palette(50), type = "heatmap")
```

This gives the following heatmap:

[image]

```
## a random set that has been sorted
hmdata_s <- matrix(data = sort(sample(x = 1:10^6, size = 100*100)), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
plot_ly(z = hmdata_s, colors = palette(50), type = "heatmap")
```

Yielding this plot:
[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

### UPDATE

you can set custom scale in `plot_ly` with `zauto`, `zmax`, and `zmin`. The following 2 pieces of code and graphs will illustrate this:

The scale is set from 1 to 100 and the data vary similarly:

```
hmdata_s3 <- matrix(data = sort(sample(x = 1:100, size = 100*100, replace = TRUE)), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
plot_ly(z = hmdata_s3, colors = palette(50), type = "heatmap", zauto = FALSE, zmin = 1, zmax = 100)
```

[image]

The scale is set from 1 to 100 and the data vary between 50 and 100 only

```
hmdata_s4 <- matrix(data = sort(sample(x = 50:100, size = 100*100, replace = TRUE)), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
plot_ly(z = hmdata_s4, colors = palette(50), type = "heatmap", zauto = FALSE, zmin = 1, zmax = 100)
```

[image]

Comment: In my data (97x138 matrix, 97 channels and 138 time stamps) I have values ranging from  0  to 10^8 and I would always like 0/1 represent dark blue, 10^8 represent dark red etc even if my data doesn't have such values in case some other data set has.

Comment: I think I understand your problem now.  Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: For some reason when I apply the palette to my data, the scale consists only of red, purple and blue, not a hint of the other defined colors. Also thanks for the zauto, zmin and zmax. Those were exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You could check your pallette with your own code: `plot(rep(1,50),col=palette(50), pch=19, cex=3)`. If this looks OK, you could have a look at the spread of your data, maybe the data are somewhat different from what you expect. As a last resort, you could restart R/RStudio and repeat these steps.

Comment: I understood that. That is exactly what the `zauto` `zmin` `zmax` accomplishes. Does it look ok if you execute the code after **update** in the answer?

Comment: Yes with your given example data or volcano data it works and looks just fine.

Comment: Similar problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535371/heatmap-colors-not-working-in-plotly

Comment: The key factor here seems to be your data and how it is distributed. Could you share your data or a sample of it?

Comment: This is fantastic help, searched for a long time to find something that would help me. I have categorical data with a custom colorbar. I am creating a function that will dynamically create a plot with multiple subplots. I don't know if they all will have all of my categories. The zmax and zmin made sure that the plot I put the legend on includes all the categories. Fantastic. Thank you.